# How can I save space in array when init with null?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, defaultifempty

I have a linq syntax to get elemnts from XML, 
this is the XML syntax:

```
<bbb ccc="12345">
  <productA>FIRST</productA>
  <!--productB>SECOND</productB-->
  <productC>THIRD</productC>
</bbb>
```

I want to init a string array with the products :

```
string[] aaa =
                 (from el in keyValueList.Elements("bbb")
                  where (string)el.Attribute("ccc") == "12345"
                  select new string[] { (el.Attribute("productA").Value), el.Attribute("productB").Value, el.Attribute("productC").Value }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I try save space when the product not found (like productB), I can not use DefaultIfEmpty() but it is not compiling...
like:

```
   string[] aaa =
                 (from el in keyValueList.Elements("bbb")
                  where (string)el.Attribute("ccc") == "12345"
                  select new string[] { (el.Attribute("productA").Value).DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty), el.Attribute("productB").Value.DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty), el.Attribute("productC").Value.DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty) }).FirstOrDefault();
```

In conclusion, I want to get this array: {"FIRST",null,"THIRD"}
  **and not {"FIRST","THIRD"}**

Can I do it?

Comment: What types does `DefaultIfEmpty` accept? What type is ...`Value`? Why are you passing `String.Empty` if you want `null`? Why do you think having `null` in the array saves space? How many items do you have that you think you need to save space?

Comment: The null item is a comment and not an element.  Why is the item commented out?

Comment: If the null item was not in comment, was not a problem! I want to Know to match a specific product to the to the suitable value from aaa string, And I try do do it by index (aaa[2] have to contain "THIRD" value (productC ) etc), if  tha aaa= {"FIRST","THIRD"} so aaa[2] was out of range or null), yes?